# TSQL - Get Data grouped by row number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with ID and Date field

```
ID     |Date
1      |2013-5-22
1      |2013-5-23
1      |2013-5-25
1      |2013-5-26
2      |2013-5-26
2      |2013-5-27
1      |2013-5-27
1      |2013-5-28
```

With the Row_Number i can group all data by id and ghet the Min date and Max Date

```
;WITH q AS(
SELECT f.*,
grp = DATEDIFF(day, 0, f.Date) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY f.ID ORDER BY f.Date),
FROM  myTable f    
)
SELECT 
MIN(q.ID) as ID,
MIN(q.Date) as StartDate,
MAX(q.Date) as EndDate
FROM q
GROUP BY q.grp, q.ID, Date
;
```

Result:

```
ID     |StartDate |EndDate
1      |2013-5-22 |2013-5-23
2      |2013-5-26 |2013-5-27
1      |2013-5-25 |2013-5-28
```

Now i need to get the date step by <= 3
Example:

```
ID     |StartDate |EndDate
1      |2013-5-22 |2013-5-23
2      |2013-5-26 |2013-5-27
1      |2013-5-25 |2013-5-27
1      |2013-5-28 |2013-5-28
```

Can someone, please, illuminate my way?
ty

**EDIT**
Sorry

```
;WITH q AS(
SELECT  f.*,
grp = DATEDIFF(day, 0, f.Date) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY f.ID ORDER BY f.Date)
FROM  MyTable f
)
SELECT 
MIN(q.ID) as ID,
MIN(q.Date) as StartDate,
MAX(q.Date) as EndDate
FROM q
GROUP BY q.grp, q.ID
;
```

Comment: Your query doesn't work because of the comma behind the row_number column. But even then it returns a different result. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8d8e2/4/0

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt had a bug, try this instead:

```
;WITH q AS(
  SELECT ID, Date,
  grp = DATEDIFF(day, 0, Date) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date)
FROM  myTable
), r as
(
  select id, date, grp, 
  (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY Date)-1)/3 a from q
)
SELECT 
MIN(ID) as ID,
MIN(Date) as StartDate,
MAX(Date) as EndDate
FROM r
GROUP BY grp, ID, a
```